# cant add tracks to spotify playlist

Tags: python, spotify

having an issue with adding tracks to a playlist . i can obtain the currently playing song and create a playlist if it doesnt already exist but once i try to add tracks to the playlist it gives me this error

An error occurred: http status: 403, code:-1
You cannot add tracks to a playlist you don't own., reason: None

```
def add_artist_songs_to_playlist():
sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uri,
                        scope="app-remote-control user-library-read user-read-playback-state  user-read-private user-read-email playlist-read-private playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private",
                        cache_path=".cache-" + username)
spotify_api = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=sp_oauth)
artist_name, artist_id = get_artist_info()
try:
    songs = []
    offset = 0
    while True:
        result = spotify_api.artist_albums(artist_id, offset=offset)
        albums = result['items']
        if not albums:
            break
        for album in albums:
            album_tracks = spotify_api.album_tracks(album['id'])
            for track in album_tracks['items']:
                songs.append(track['id'])
        offset += 20
    spotify_api.playlist_add_items(playlist_id, songs)
    print(f"Successfully added {len(songs)} songs to the playlist!")
except spotipy.client.SpotifyException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Answer (score 1):

How do you get `playlist_id`? It is likely not allowing you modify a playlist that does not belong to the authenticated user.

You can try getting the current user's playlists and see if the `playlist_id` you are trying to modify is listed in there: https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/#spotipy.client.Spotify.current_user_playlists

Comment: the script creates a playlist , then adds the discography of the artist of the currently playing song to it . the playlist is created just fine so i know for a fact that it belongs to the authenticated user

Comment: @AmpujaKid It is not possible to further debug this without additional information. Can you add the code that creates the playlist to your question?